# SQL Union Select Order by inner query then by entire union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a SQL UNION string that looks like this and works (the `{dData}` and similar placeholders are filled in by VB.Net code):

```
SELECT LEFT({dData}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
    {dData}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, 
    {dLov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
FROM {dData} 
INNER JOIN {dLov} ON ({dData}.ROAD_NAME = {dLov}.ROAD_NAME) AND ({dData}.READER = {dLov}.READER) 
WHERE ({dData}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {dData}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
    AND (LEN(COALESCE({dData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({dData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
    AND {dData}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
    AND {dData}.PLATE = @pf 
UNION 
SELECT LEFT({vData}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
    {vData}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, 
    {vLov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
FROM {vData} 
INNER JOIN {vLov} ON {vData}.CAMERA = {vLov}.CAMERA 
WHERE ({vData}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {vData}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
    AND (LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
    AND {vData}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
    AND {vData}.PLATE = @pf 
ORDER BY LPRReadDate
```

The problem is I need to get the Top 1 and Order the second Select statement by LPRRead Date in Descending Order.  I tried doing it like this.

```
SELECT LEFT({dData}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
    {dData}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, 
    {dLov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
FROM {dData} 
INNER JOIN {dLov} ON ({dData}.ROAD_NAME = {dLov}.ROAD_NAME) AND ({dData}.READER = {dLov}.READER) 
WHERE ({dData}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {dData}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
    AND (LEN(COALESCE({dData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({dData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
    AND {dData}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
    AND {dData}.PLATE = @pf 
UNION 
(SELECT TOP 1 LEFT({vData}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
    {vData}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, 
    {vLov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
FROM {vData} 
INNER JOIN {vLov} ON {vData}.CAMERA = {vLov}.CAMERA 
WHERE ({vData}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {vData}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
    AND (LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
    AND {vData}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
    AND {vData}.PLATE = @pf 
ORDER BY {vLov}.CREATED_DT DESC)  
ORDER BY LPRReadDate
```

But, I am getting this error:

> Syntax Error near 'ORDER'.

I am sure that I need to do some kind of sub-query. I've tried to figure it out by looking at examples online, but I can't figure it out.

***Update***
@UnhandledExcepSean I tried adapting what you said to my code.  After a couple more syntax errors, I arrived at the code below.  But whenever I try to run it, it just times out the server.  Can you tell me if it looks correct or if there are any changes that might need to be made....

```
SELECT 
  Plates, LPRReadDate, LPRLocation 
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        LEFT({vData}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, {vData}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, {vLov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
    FROM {vData} 
    INNER JOIN {vLov} ON {vData}.CAMERA = {vLov}.CAMERA 
    WHERE ({vData}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {vData}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
        AND (LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
        AND {vData}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
        AND {vData}.PLATE = @pf 
    ORDER BY {vLov}.CREATED_DT DESC
    ) test 
UNION
SELECT LEFT({EOCdata}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
    {EOCdata}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, 
    {EOClov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
FROM {EOCdata} 
INNER JOIN {EOClov} ON ({EOCdata}.CAMERA = {EOClov}.CAMERA) AND ({EOCdata}.READER = {EOClov}.READER) 
WHERE ({EOCdata}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {EOCdata}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
    AND (LEN(COALESCE({EOCdata}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({EOCdata}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
    AND {EOCdata}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
    AND {EOCdata}.PLATE = @pf 
ORDER BY LPRReadDate
```

Comment: @Aurelian actually you can in SQL Server as long as you specify a TOP # of records... at least with subqueries. I've never tried in a union.

Comment: Thanks @UnhandledExcepSean. I will remove my comment.

Comment: Can you run the SQL manually and see what the times are on each side of the union? I will say that to get really accurate answers, you'd need to provide a bunch more information. Table and index definitions at a minimum; anything less is people guessing.

Comment: I'll try to explain this, but bare with me.  There are more Unions than I posted.  All of the SELECTs, minus the 'TOP 1' SELECT, have clear fields that are being joined.  Unfortunately, the 'TOP 1' can only be Joined on 1 field, and that field in the LOV table has multiple values that it joins on.  So on {vData}.CAMERA = {vLov}.CAMERA, {vLOV}.CAMERA has duplicates.  This is because the person who maintains this table needs to get rid of some old stuff. But for now, I just need to get whatever match has the latest CREATED_DT from {vLOV}.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: sounds like you want to learn about the APPLY operator. Maybe able to replace some of the JOINs this way and simplify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.  I was finally able to work out how to do it.  In case anyone might find it useful, I'll post what I came up with below. The derivedTable portion is that part that I was trying to figure out.

```
        WITH derivedTable 
        AS 
        (
            SELECT {vLov}.LPR_VIGILANT_LOV_ID, 
            {vLov}.CAMERA, 
            {vLov}.LOCATION, 
            {vLov}.CREATED_DT, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By {vLov}.CAMERA 
                                ORDER BY {vLov}.CREATED_DT DESC) rn 
            FROM {vLov}
        ) 
        SELECT LEFT({vData}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
        {vData}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate,          
        derivedTable.LOCATION 
        FROM {vData} 
        INNER JOIN derivedTable ON {vData}.CAMERA = derivedTable.CAMERA 
        WHERE ({vData}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {vData}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
        AND (LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({vData}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
        AND {vData}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
        AND {vData}.LOCATION = @lf 
        AND derivedTable.rn = 1 
        UNION 
        SELECT LEFT({EOCdata}.PLATE,7) AS Plates, 
            {EOCdata}.SIGHTING_DT AS LPRReadDate, 
            {EOClov}.LOCATION AS LPRLocation 
        FROM {EOCdata} 
        INNER JOIN {EOClov} ON ({EOCdata}.CAMERA = {EOClov}.CAMERA) AND ({EOCdata}.READER = {EOClov}.READER) 
        WHERE ({EOCdata}.SIGHTING_DT >= @sdate AND {EOCdata}.SIGHTING_DT <= @edate) 
        AND (LEN(COALESCE({EOCdata}.PLATE,'')) = @slen1 OR LEN(COALESCE({EOCdata}.PLATE,'')) = @slen2) 
        AND {EOCdata}.PLATE NOT LIKE @rx1 
        AND {EOCdata}.LOCATION = @lf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the issue thusly:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Field1 INT,Field2 INT)
INSERT INTO @t (Field1,Field2) SELECT 1,1
INSERT INTO @t (Field1,Field2) SELECT 2,2
INSERT INTO @t (Field1,Field2) SELECT 3,3

SELECT
    Field1,Field2
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1
        Field1,Field2
    FROM @t
    ORDER BY Field1 ASC
) test
UNION
SELECT
    Field1,Field2
FROM @t
ORDER BY Field2 DESC
```

Comment: @UnhandledExepSean Can you take a look at my updated question?